# Karma fails to capture Internet Explorer 10 on 64-bit Windows

Tags: internet-explorer, testing, launch, karma-runner

I am trying to launch IE through karma test. But it's failing! Below is the error log:

```
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.4 server started at http://127.0.0.1:9876/projects/client/layout/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser IE
ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start IE

INFO [launcher]: Trying to start IE again.
ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start IE

INFO [launcher]: Trying to start IE again.
ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start IE

INFO [IE 10.0.0 (Windows 7)]: Connected on socket ysUM5iinHcFBqqDO0Gp1
```

Any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

After Installing Karma-ie-launcher, change the index.js to the following file.

https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ie-launcher/pull/9

Answer (score 0):

I've one more solution at least for IE 9 (IE9)

If you look closely, the process being launched by `npm\node_modules\karma\lib\launchers\process.js` is :

```
[self._process = spawn(cmd, args);]

c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe -extoff http://localhost:9876/?id=51299470
```

this causes issue for me.

If you launch this from command line you can see the browser wont start.

For now the solution is to remove the -extoff param. This can be done via modifying:
`npm\node_modules\karma-ie-launcher\index.js`

search for `-extoff` and replace it with `""` (Zero length string).

Now this is working for me.